# Importing Specific Columns into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Column 'Record Type' and Column 1 are the same thing.

In the top instance below, I am saying header=0, and in the bottom instance I am saying header=None.

I am failing to see why the NaN result switches when stating the column number vs the column name.

Input:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\dusti\Desktop\bulk export.xlsx', sheet_name=1, header=0) 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= [1,'Record Type'])
print (df)
```

Results:

```
    1            Record Type
0 NaN               Campaign
1 NaN  Campaign By Placement
2 NaN  Campaign By Placement
3 NaN  Campaign By Placement
```

Input:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\dusti\Desktop\bulk export.xlsx', sheet_name=1, header=None) 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= [1,'Record Type'])
print (df)
```

Results:

```
                       1  Record Type
0            Record Type          NaN
1               Campaign          NaN
2  Campaign By Placement          NaN
3  Campaign By Placement          NaN
4  Campaign By Placement          NaN
```

[image: excel file]

Comment: Is it possible to upload a screenshot of your excel file, please?

Comment: Stating header=0 and not being able to reference the header names makes sense to me. What doesn't make sense is why I cannot reference the column number in both instances.

Answer (score 0):

In the second form (header=None), the column names in `data` are 0 and 1, so when you create your dataframe `df` based on `data` only the column 1 is used. As the other column `Record Type` does not exist in `data`, the column is filled by `NaN`.

In the first form this is the same thing. You cannot mix column position and column name.

You should read the documentation about `usecols` parameter of [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) function.